# SharePoint Dataform webpart redirection issue

Tags: sharepoint, dataformwebpart

I have two web parts in my sharepoint aspx web page. One is Content editor web part and the other is data form web part.

In data form web part, I have a data view and I need to pass a parameter "id" to this dataview which will show the project details in the data view. I tried to use a value from a control as a parameter and never had a success. I did googled a lot last few days and haven't found any solution. It would be great, if someone show me a way to use the text from a control (may be a text box or select control). if someone have a working sample, please share. Alternatively I have used a query string as a parameter (eventhough I prefer to use text from a control). We need to pass a query string called id. For example, I am navigating to `http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=7`. This will show the project details of project id 7 in data form web part. this works fine.

I need to provide an option to user to enter the project id instead of modifying the query string in url. To achieve that I used content editor web part and I have a text box text1 and a submit button (html controls). The user will enter project id in the text box provided and will click the submit button to view the project details in dataview. The submit button javascript code has the following code:

```
        url = 'http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=7';
        alert (url); //alerts as http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=7
        window.location = url;
```

For testing purpose, I just hardcoded the url. However, clicking the submit button is not redirecting to `http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=7` or something happens during redirect. The page just reloads once. i.e., if I am in `http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=12` and clicking the submit button reloads the page `http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=12` instead of navigating to `http://localhost/pages/1.aspx?id=7`.

Without data form web part, the redirect works fine. Kindly help.

Thank you